# How would you build a production ready authentication system for a GraphQL API built with Rails and React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, graphql, production-environment

I am trying to integrate an authentication system with Graphql and rails that communicates with a React front end and I would like to know what is the best way to do it for a production environment

I know that this might involve using jwt but I would like to know how would you do it?

When the user signs in/up from the react front end it sends the request to the rails graphql api that authenticates the user. Then when the authenticated user makes a request/query it, the backend first makes sure that the user has access to the resources that he is requesting and then send those resources in json to the react front end

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an open-ended question. It's probably not really possible to write a specific answer to your question, but here goes nothing.

There are multiple ways to set up authentication with GraphQL. First of all, it's important to understand whether your user is allowed to make any GraphQL queries at all *without* being authenticated.

You're saying you're authenticating the user with your Rails GraphQL API. Are you doing this with a mutation or with a REST call? If it's just REST and the user isn't allowed to use the GraphQL API without authenticating then you may just be able to block the user from interacting with the GraphQL API at all, when they're not authenticated.

Otherwise it's common to check whether the user is authenticated and if so keep the user data in your GraphQL query context. Then you'll now — per query — whether the user is authenticated.

When the user is attempting to access any resource that they may not be able to see or are attempting to send a mutation without being authenticated, then you can just end the entire query/request with a GraphQL error.

Since GraphQL errors are still considered part of a successful *HTTP request* you can handle them as usual in your front end as part of the UI. They'll be listed in the usual errors array of the response, as specified in the GraphQL spec.

Regarding JWT, you can of course use JWT to authenticate the user, which requires you to either store a token in a cookie or somewhere else in the user's browser. Typically you'd just send the token in the `Authorization` header with every GraphQL request.